# EF Core load references of unknown entity

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, restful-architecture, ef-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

DISCLAIMER: Since we are all familiar with it, i will be using [contoso university](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1) design to explain my question. Also, i am using EF core and .net core 2.0 on a mvc code first design.

[image: contoso university]

I am developing a very generic RESTful API that works on any model. It has one method for each of create, read, update and delete operation in only one controller, the route of this is

```
[Route("/api/{resource}")]
```

Resource is the entity that the client wants to work with, for example if someone wants to get all **Courses** using the api he has to do a GET request on http://www.example.com/api/course/ or http://www.example.com/api/course/2 to get one by id and the following code will do the job.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int:min(1)?}")]
public IActionResult Read([FromRoute] string resource, [FromRoute] int? id)
{
    //find resourse in models 
    IEntityType entityType = _context.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.EndsWith($".{resource}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (entityType == null) return NotFound(resource);

    Type type = entityType.ClrType; 

    if (id == null)//select all from table
    {
        var entityRows = context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(context, null);

        if (entityRows == null)
            return NoContent();

        //TODO: load references (1)

        return Ok(entityRows);
    }
    else //select by id
    {
        var entityRow = _context.Find(type, id);
        if (entityRow == null)
            return NoContent();

        //TODO: load references (2)

        return Ok(entityRows);
    }
}
```

This small piece of code will do the magic with one small exception, intermediate collections will not be loaded. Given our example, the fetched course or courses will have no info for **CourseInstructor** (the intermediate collection in between Course and Person). I am trying to find a way to Eager load the navigation properties only if it is a collection; or by any other condition that will ensure that only many-to-many relationships are loaded.

For //TODO: load reference (2) i could use

```
_context.Entry(entityRow).Collection("CourseInsructor").Load();
```

On runtime if i could find all the navigation properties (filtered by spoken condition) and foreach of them i did Load(), i should get the desired result. My problem is when i get all (when id is null) the entityRows is type 'InternalDbSet' which is an unknown model.

So for the two TODOs i need some help on doing the following steps

1: find navigation properties of many-to-many relationships only
2: load them

Any suggestions?

Comment: EF core doesn't yet have lazy loading.

Comment: I know, that is why i want to eager load.

Comment: But you said *intermediate collections will not be loaded because of lazy loading*. That's not true because there is no lazy loading. I'm just pointing that out.

Comment: Corrected, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this seems like a very bad idea to me. While the CRUD stuff is going to be identical for most resources, there will be variances (as you've now run into). There's also something to be said for having a self-documenting API: with individual controllers, you know which resources can be accessed by nature of having a controller associated with that resource. With they way you're doing it, it's a complete black box. This also will of course effect any sort of *actual* generated API documentation. For example, if you were to include Swagger in your project, it would not be able to determine what you're doing here. Finally, you're now having to use reflection for *everything*, which will effect your performance.

What I would suggest instead is creating a base abstract controller and then creating a controller for each unique resource that inherits from that, for example:

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntity> : Controller
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    protected readonly MyContext _context;

    public BaseController(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    ...

    [HttpGet("create")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
       var model = new TEntity();
       return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TEntity model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(model);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    ...
}
```

I just wanted to give a quick example, but you'd build out all the rest of the CRUD methods in the same fashion, generically using `TEntity`. Then, for each actual resource, you simply do:

```
public class WidgetController : BaseController<Widget>
{
    public WidgetController(MyContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

No duplication of code, but you've now got an actual real controller backing the resource, aiding both the innate and possibly explicit documentation of your API. And, no reflection anywhere.

Then, to solve problems like what you have here, you can add hooks to your base controller: essentially just virtual methods that are utilized in your base controller's CRUD actions and do nothing or just default things. However, you can then override these in your derived controllers to stub in additional functionality. For example, you can add something like:

```
  public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable()
      => _context.Set<TEntity>();
```

Then, in your derived controller, you can do something like:

```
public class CourseController : BaseController<Course>
{
    ...

    public override IQueryable<Course> GetQueryable()
        => base.GetQueryable().Include(x => x.CourseInstructors).ThenInclude(x => x.Instructor);
```

So, for example, you'd make your `BaseController.Index` action, perhaps, utilize `GetQueryable()` to get the list of entities to display. Simply by overriding this on the derived class, you can alter what happens based on the context of a particular type of resource.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the heads up, unfortunately it's too late to go back. This design might have difficulties and cons but it also have pros, considering the business factors this approach suites well. All problems that i have stumbled upon were taken care of and if the project is complete i will be able to reuse this code for every mvc solution. BTW, this design was suggested by a python developer.